# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I keep getting this error. I have no idea how to fix it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.DownloadFile("https://cdn.meme.am/instances/60569499.jpg", @"C:\Users\fatih\Desktop");

}
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: Error messages have details in C#. It should say what happened. What do you see in Chrome when you go to the web page? Does the directory exist where you want to save the file?

Comment: its my website so the file is ready to go and the error message is not helping really

Comment: The message and inner execption will help **us**.  That's why **we** are asking for it.  But (a) `itzyzex.comlu.com` doesn't exist and (b) you need to specify a file name as well as the path like `C:\Users\fatih\Desktop\stuff\file.png` otherwise it's trying to overwrite the `stuff` directory and failing.  `stuff` also needs to exist.

Comment: but i need a file for that website how do it then

Comment: `itzyzex.comlu.com’s server DNS address could not be found` if you need that file you're SOL because the site is dead.

Comment: It still wont work tried a another site

Comment: @FatihTkale Can you update the code in your question with your latest attempt please?

Comment: FYI: I copy/pasted http://itzyzex.comlu.com into my browser and loads fine, and the http://itzyzex.comlu.com/itzy.PNG also works

Answer (score 0):

check The WebException has an InnerException, which will say:

Access to the path C:\Users\fatih\Desktop is denied.

Write to a file, not to folder

just add filename C:\Users\fatih\Desktop\file[.extention]

*make sure you have authorization to access those location